# Plotting the probability distribution in different variables

Tags: r, plot, histogram, lines

My data, ret, includes 3 variables and 208 rows for each variable.

```
dim(ret)
[1] 208   3
```

I do the plot one by one for different variables.

```
hist(ret$AAPL,breaks
     freq=F,
     main="The probaility distribution of AAPL",
     xlab="AAPL")
hist(ret$GOOGL,breaks
     freq=F,
     main="The probaility distribution of GOOGL",
     xlab="GOOGL")
hist(ret$WMT,breaks
     freq=F,
     main="The probaility distribution of WMT",
     xlab="WMT")
```

Now,I try to use sapply function to plot variables separately in one time.

```
sapply(ret, function(x) hist(x,breaks=100,
                             freq=F,
                             main="the probaility distribution of x",
                             xlab="x"))
```

However, "main="the probaility distribution of x"" and "xlab=x" do not work. I try to put the colnames in x.

In addition, I also try to put the line in the plot together with variables. The function I use is

```
lines(density(,main="",lty=1,lwd=1)
```

If I plot separately with variables, I do

```
hist(ret$AAPL,breaks
     freq=F,
     main="the probaility distribution of AAPL",
     xlab="AAPL")
lines(density(ret$AAPL),main="AAPL",lty=1,lwd=1)
```

But how to use sapply function to do it together? 
Could someone please tell me how to solve the problems:
using sapply function to plot the probability distribution with the line of probability density for different variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some quantmod and ggplot2 packages for this task. Just ignore this if your question is really specific to `hist` and `sapply`.

```
library(ggplot2) # to access round_any
library(quantmod)

getSymbols(c("AAPL","GOOGL","WMT"))

A=data.frame('aapl',AAPL$AAPL.Close)
G=data.frame('goog',GOOGL$GOOGL.Close)
M=data.frame('wmt',WMT$WMT.Close)
names(A)=names(G)=names(M)=c('symbol','close')
d=rbind(A,G,M)

m <- ggplot(d, aes(x=close, colour=symbol, group=symbol))
m + geom_density(fill=NA)
```

[image]

or if you want a histogram

```
m <- ggplot(d, aes(x=close, colour=symbol, group=symbol))
m + geom_histogram(fill=NA,position='dodge')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I'm assuming your data.frame `ret` has returns, not prices, but the basic methodology should work in either case.

[image]

```
# set up example - you have this already...
library(quantmod)    # for getSymbols
symbols <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "WMT")
ret     <- do.call(merge,lapply(symbols,function(s)dailyReturn(Cl(getSymbols(s,src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)))))
names(ret) <- symbols
ret     <- data.frame(date=index(ret), ret)
# you start here...
plot.hist <- function(x,s) {
  hist(x,breaks=100,freq=F,xlab=s,main=paste("Histogram of",s), xlim=0.1*c(-1,1))
  lines(density(x, na.rm=TRUE),lty=1,lwd=1)
}
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
mapply(plot.hist, ret[,2:4], symbols)
```

There are a few nuances here.

First, you want the stock symbol in the title, not the character string "x". To do that you need to use `paste(...)` as above.

Second, when using `sapply(...)` on a data.frame the columns are indeed passed to the function, but the **column names** are not. So we have to pass both. The easiest way to do this is with `mapply(...)` (read the docs).

Finally, as pointed out in the other answer, you can indeed use ggplot for this, which I also recommend:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)    # for melt(...)
gg.df <- melt(ret, id="date", variable.name="Stock", value.name="Return")
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=Return))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill=Stock),color="grey80",binwidth=0.005)+
  stat_density(geom="line")+
  facet_grid(Stock~.)
```

[image]